# Does having the ability to cast focus spells count for things that require you to be able to cast spells?

Tags: spells, spellcasting, pathfinder-2e

I was looking at the new shadowcaster archetype. Taking the archetype has a prerequisite of being able to cast a spell.

Can a ranger take it, since they have the Warden spells and take the shadow hound animal companion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes

In the [Ranger Class Description](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=9) *Warden Spells* are defined as a type of focus spell.

> Certain feats grant you warden spells, which are a type of focus spells.

And the rules on [Focus Spells](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=276) define this for non-spellcasters:

> You gain the ability to Cast a Spell and use any spellcasting actions necessary to cast your focus spells (see below). However, you don’t qualify for feats and other rules that require you to be a spellcaster.

The prerequisites on archetypes are quite precise in what you need to fulfill them. While some call for a specific class ([Runelord](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=103)) others call for the *spellcasting class feature* ([Hellknight Signifier](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=26)).  There are also archetypes that require *spell slots* ([Geomancer](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=100)) or a *spell repertoire* ([Wellspring Mage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=104)).
And then there is those that require the ability to cast spells from a defined tradition ([Soulforger](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=102)) or to cast *Focus Spells* ([Magic Warrior](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=19)).

[Shadowcaster](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=101) doesn't specify any of this. It just requires you to be able to cast a spell. Even a [*Innate Spell*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=279) gained from a ancestry would fulfill this requirement, as they allow you to cast spells.

> You can cast your innate spells even if you aren't a member of a spellcasting class.

Comment: by extension would that also apply to ancestry feats that grant cantrips?

Comment: Good point! I expanded my answer to cover that as well.